# Add <code> around selected text with nicEdit

Tags: javascript, html, tags, selection, nicedit

I am looking for a way to add < code> tags around a selected text with nicEdit. As well as removing these tags when selecting the text again.

The reason for this is that I want a user to be able to mark text in the textarea as code, or whatever other tag I may want for that matter.

I need to be able to mark several rows, and I need the html formating of the selected text to stay the same wether it is marked as code or not. You get the jest.

I have tried this function:

```
customButtonOptions = {
buttons : {
    'code' : {name : __('Mark text as code'), type : 'nicEditorCodeButton'}},
                iconFiles : {'code' : '../code.gif'}

                };

nicEditorCodeButton = nicEditorButton.extend({

mouseClick : function() {
var dataValue = 'code';
document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, '<'+dataValue+'>');
selectedElement = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
            selectedElement.className = "codePrint";
    }
});

nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,customButtonOptions);
```

But for code or span tags(which I also need) it doesnt work(one row only). It does however work for pre tags, but that doesnt help me.

It is also not the best option of setting the class as it depends on the parent node, it would have been much easier if I could add:

```
Normal text in the textarea
<code class="codePrint"> selected text </code> (ofc this part should be html and actually render)
Rest of the text in the text area
```

I have also tried selectionStart, selectionEnd, but these only return as undefined and I cant solve it.

Is there anyone who can help me? I am getting really desperate and I have searched the whole web(well, maybe not) to find an answer, but I cant :s

Ps. Only needs to work for newer browsers

Comment: you already asked same question here:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909404/insert-html-tags-around-selected-text-in-nicedit

Comment: @Sudhir Yes I did, but I got no useful replies and for some reason I can't edit it.